# Plist Root, unable to get proper count

Tags: plist

I'm using Xcode 4.6

When I make a plist for my app is has a root line already in it.

This is causing me some problems. 
When I make my list I leave root as a dictionary then add a line and make it an array and fill it with objects then make a line under the last object and make it an array and move it left.

So on an so forth, untilI have 3 arrays made under Root.

Each array has 7 items in it, when I use the code to show the count of my plist ** return [plistname count]; ***

I only get 3 lines in my table view, not 7?

I have tried making root an array, making my arrays dictionaries, all kinds if things but nothing seems to work right.

I am using a YouTube video to learn how to do this, my code matches hers exactly except my plist is not blank on creation..., it has a Root line that I cannot get rid of and have not been able to find ANY other resources on the web about plist that have a Root line or how to get rid if it.

In every video I have found about plist, they are all blank in creation and the count function works fine for them, mine will only count the three main items but I need it to count the items in the first array to display they table properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> untilI have 3 arrays made under Root.

Why are you surprised `[plistname count]` returns 3?

Comment: Well in the video they stated that as they add items it would automatically adjust the count properly, but I am getting the notion that they made a bit of a mistake, they had four sections and four items in each. So I'm guessing if they added a 5th item to each section, they would still only have 4 items in their table?  I guess I'll just return 7  and keep it simple. The "Root" showing up in my plist threw me off I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Well I got it all working exactly like it should, the only thing I did different (other than have different info in my plist) is instead of return [plistname count];. I just used return [productNamesArray count];  now my table populates with the correct number of items and will auto adjust if I remove or add items.